# Function to calculate days between 2 given dates sometimes produce inaccurate result

Tags: javascript, days

I have a days between function that is supposed to count the number of days accurately between two dates, here is the code:

```js
function DaysBetween(str1, str2) {
  var date1 = str1;
  var date2 = str2;
  date1 = date1.split("/");
  date2 = date2.split("/");
  var oneday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1e3;
  date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[0], date1[1]);
  date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[0], date2[1]);
  var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / oneday));
  if (diffDays == 0) {
    diffDays = 1;
  }

  console.log(diffDays);
  return diffDays;
}
DaysBetween("9/24/2019","10/1/2019")
```

this works fine sometimes, but sometimes it gives an inaccurate number of days.

For example if `date1 = 09/24/2019` and `date2 = 09/25/2019` it returns a correct answer of "1" or `date1 = 09/24/2019` and `date2 = 09/30/2019` it returns correct answer of 6 days, however if I input the dates of `date1 = 09/24/2019` and `date2 = 10/01/2019` it returns "8 days" when it should be 7. What gives?

Comment: What about difference in days between Feb 27,2020 and March 1, 2020?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, the months starts from 0 if not supplied as a date string.

For example, `new Date(2019,0,1)` will return *Jan 1, 2019* and `new Date(2019,1,1)` will return *Feb 1, 2019*

At the same time, `new Date("2019/1/1")` will return *Jan 1, 2019*

```js
console.log(new Date(2019,0,1).toString())
console.log(new Date(2019,1,1).toString())
```

In your code, it calculates the difference between *Oct 24, 2019* and *Nov 1, 2019*. October have 31 days hence 8 is the right answer. To get the difference for *Sep 24, 2019* and *Oct 1, 2019*, you need to reduce 1 from the value of month.

You need to correct your code to the following

```
date1 = new Date(date1[2], parseInt(date1[0])-1, date1[1]);
date2 = new Date(date2[2], parseInt(date2[0])-1, date2[1]);
```

```js
function DaysBetween(str1, str2) {
  var date1 = str1;
  var date2 = str2;
  date1 = date1.split("/");
  date2 = date2.split("/");
  var oneday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1e3;
  date1 = new Date(date1[2], parseInt(date1[0]) - 1, date1[1]);
  date2 = new Date(date2[2], parseInt(date2[0]) - 1, date2[1]);
  var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / oneday));
  if (diffDays == 0) {
    diffDays = 1;
  }

  console.log(diffDays);
  return diffDays;
}
DaysBetween("9/24/2019", "10/1/2019");
```

And here's a suggestion. You don't need all these lines. This can be easily done by the following code

```
function dateDiff(d1,d2){
  return (new Date(d2).getTime() - new Date(d1).getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Which will get the time in unix timestamp, find difference and then divide it by *1000 * 60 * 60 * 24* to find days.

```js
function dateDiff(d1,d2){
  return (new Date(d2).getTime() - new Date(d1).getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}

console.log(dateDiff("2019/9/24","2019/10/1"));
```

Comment: Will that account for things like day lights saving time and stuff like that?

Comment: @tony The last one? When you pass a date string without time to `new Date()`, the date returned will have the time _00:00:00_.

Answer (score 0):

A true Date object, in many languages, is a numeric representation of time from some Epoch value. Javascript uses the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch of 1 January 1970, Midnight. So to find the difference between two dates, it can be simple math:

*For d1 = '2020-01-01' and d2 = '2021-01-01'*

```
new Date(d2) - new Date(d1)
```

Which will give you a number of milliseconds difference between the two dates. If you want, you can check if `d1` is less than `d2` or whatever, or you can just set the absolute value to get the difference, regardless of which one is greater. Note that this does not take a `time` element into consideration. If you want to factor for that, there are a couple of more steps.

But now that we've got a difference in milliseconds, we need to convert that to days.

There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in one day, so we can just divide our value by that to get days.

```
(new Date(d2) - new Date(d1))/86400000
```

But that will potentially give us a decimal number. So we need to get rid of that. `Math` to the rescue again.

```
Math.floor( Math.abs((new Date(d2) - new Date(d1)))/86400000 )
```

Then we make this all into a function so we can reuse it.

```
function getDaysBetween(d1,d2){
  return ( Math.floor( Math.abs((new Date(d2) - new Date(d1)))/86400000 ) ) ;
}
```

So `console.log( getDaysDiff('2020-01-01','2021-01-01') ) ;` will give us `366`. Javascript `Date` object does take into account Leap Days, but it doesn't account for Leap Seconds. If that's a concern, you'll have to account for it. Also note that if you are taking care of dates from different time zones, you may have to account for that also. My function above only calculates for full days difference. So if you have two dates from two timezones (1 Jan 2019 0100 EST and 2 Jan 2019 0100 PST), you may want to account correctly for timezone differences.

Also, I'm not doing any error checking to validate you pass the function a valid date. If it's invalid, you'll get a `NaN` result.

```js
function getDaysBetween(d1,d2){
  return ( Math.floor( Math.abs((new Date(d2) - new Date(d1)))/86400000 ) ) ;
}

console.log( getDaysBetween('2020-01-01','2021-01-01') ) ;


d1 = '09/24/2019' ;
d2 = '09/30/2019' ;
d3 = '10/01/2019' ;

console.log(getDaysBetween(d1,d2)); //6
console.log(getDaysBetween(d1,d3)); //7
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tgy4qr7n/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date